# I want to Use Exception Handling in Javascript / Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My function is like this

```
// JavaScript Document


$('#MyFormSubmit').submit(function(){

    try{
    /* Ajax - 1 */
    $.ajax({
           url: 'Any',
           type: 'GET',
           data: 'ID',
           contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {
               alert("Success - 1");               
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert("Error - 1");
            }
        });

    /* Ajax - 2 */
    $.ajax({
           url: 'Any',
           type: 'GET',
           data: 'ID',
           contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {
               alert("Success - 2");               
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert("Error - 2");
            }
        });

    /* Ajax - 3 */
    $.ajax({
           url: 'Any',
           type: 'GET',
           data: 'ID',
           contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {
               alert("Success - 3");               
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert("Error - 3");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        alert(e);   
    }

});
```

where 1 get first error, then I want stop execution of next ajax ?
How to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plese Write Code in this way

```
function fnMyFunction1(){
  try{
   if(success){
     // call fnMyFunction2
   }
   else{
     // Show Error message
   }
  }
  catch(e){
     // Show Exception message
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Within the error block of first ajax call, just add `return false`.

```
error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert("Error - 1");
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch to handle exception.

The try statement lets you test a block of code for errors.

The catch statement lets you handle the error.

The throw statement lets you create custom errors.

```
try {
   try_statements
   if(condition)    throw "Error";

}
[catch (exception_var_1 if condition_1) {
   catch_statements_1
}]
...
[catch (exception_var_2) {
   catch_statements_2
}]
[finally {
   finally_statements
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest your ajax calls, because your calls are asynchronous, every call will immediately proceed to the next without waiting for the request to finish. Hence:

```
$('#MyFormSubmit').submit(function(){

    try{
    /* Ajax - 1 */
    $.ajax({
           url: 'Any',
           type: 'GET',
           data: 'ID',
           contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {
               alert("Success - 1");        
                /* Ajax - 2 */
                $.ajax({
                       url: 'Any',
                       type: 'GET',
                       data: 'ID',
                       contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                       success: function (data) {
                           alert("Success - 2");    
                            /* Ajax - 3 */
                            $.ajax({
                                   url: 'Any',
                                   type: 'GET',
                                   data: 'ID',
                                   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                                   success: function (data) {
                                       alert("Success - 3");               
                                    },
                                    error: function (x, y, z) {
                                        alert("Error - 3");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            catch(e){
                                alert(e);   
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (x, y, z) {
                            alert("Error - 2");
                        }
                    });
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert("Error - 1");
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following coding style

```
function f1(){
  try{
   if(success){
     // call f2
   }
   else{
     // Show Error message
   }
  }
  catch(e){
     // Show Exception message
  }
}
```